# get() returned more than one HorseEquipment -- it returned 3! in Django RESTApi

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to make a REST Api GET View in Django using serializers and raw query like this:

```
class HorseEquipmentView(APIView):
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'horse'

    def get (self, request, format = None):
        horse = 1     
        if horse != None:
            equipment = HorseEquipment.objects.raw('SELECT H.horse_id, E.name FROM horse_equipment H JOIN equipment E ON H.equipment_id = E.id WHERE H.horse_id =' + str(horse))
            serializer = HorseEquipmentSerializer(equipment, many = True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            return Response(status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

but on my localhost is returning error "get() returned more than one HorseEquipment -- it returned 3!". What can I change to make it work?

Edit:
This is my model HorseEquipment:

```
class HorseEquipment(models.Model):
    horse = models.OneToOneField(Horse, models.DO_NOTHING, primary_key=True)
    equipment = models.ForeignKey(Equipment, models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'horse_equipment'
        unique_together = (('horse', 'equipment'),)
```

and serializer:

```
class HorseEquipmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = HorseEquipment
        fields = ('horse', 'equipment')
```

Comment: Show your model `HorseEquipment`. Also the way you are making queries you are **vulnerable to SQL Injection**

Comment: I've edited my post and added my model and serializer.

Comment: Can you share your full stacktrace? @crowlek

Comment: Why do you want to make a .raw() query? I believe you can get the same result with `HorseEquipment.objects.filter(horse_id=horse).select_related('equipment')` and **avoid the SQL-injection** with that.

Comment: @SMoenig but your filter gives me equipment id instead of name of equipment

Comment: The [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) should load the `equipment`-object so that you should be able to get the name with `equipment.equipment.name`.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why you are using `raw` rather than `get`?

```py
horse_equipement = HorseEquipment.objects.get(horse_id=horse)
equipement = horse_equipement.equipment
```